# Single line "FromValue - ToValue" (Not a Class, not a Dictionary/List/Array). Howto?

Tags: c#

How often are you into a fromdate-todate scenario. 
Or perhaps a fromValue-toValue.

How do you do those times? 
I use one of those commonly,

T = ObjectType (DateTime, int, string..)

`Dictionary<T,T>` (used with .Single())

`T fromDate;`
`T toDate;`

`T[] comparison;`

Which are directly used or returned by a method.

Very Very seldom i stand create a whole object

```
public struct T 
{
   T fromDate { get; set;}
   T toDate { get; set;}
}

public Method T(params)
{
   ..some operations..
   return T { fromDate = someBegin, toDate = someEnd };
}
```

Everytime time, I want a stright and simple `KeyValuePair<T,T> test;`. The problem to me, using KeyValuePair, is missleading if used this way?? If I see a KeyValuePair in someones code, i look at the variable like "index 10, category books".

What are your suggestion?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your question.

Comment: @Ash: He's looking for a way to represent two values of the same type (e.g. fromDate and toDate) in a single variable without having to create a separate class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have .NET Framework 4, I'd suggest to use [`Tuple<T, T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx) instead, since it does not imply a key-value-relationship like `KeyValuePair`.

Comment: Tuple values have to be assigned directly on initialization?

Comment: just a shame its a bit clunky +1

Comment: @Jonas: Yes, Tuples are immutable objects. This is has a lot of advantages, because it means that you can treat them (almost) like value types, without all the problems associated with mutable structs. But, of course, you are free to *declare* the variable and *assign* it later: `Tuple<int, int> myTuple; /* some more code */; myTuple = Tuple.Create(2, 3)`.

Comment: Heinzi, thank's for answer. Of course! But (I can't edit the question to involve Tuple now), this is the nearest we came? I mean, this kind of demand must have ben for hundreds of thousand of times before (and outside) .NET 4?

Comment: If you want mutability then you can fall back to using a plain array: `var myArray = new[] { 2, 3 }`, and using `myArray[0]` etc isn't any more or less readable than using `myTuple.Item1`. I personally wouldn't use `Tuple` or array for something like this. For short-lived locals I'd probably use an anon type, `var myRange = new { From = 2, To = 3 }`; for anything else, what's wrong with a generic `Range` class/struct, [similar to what Hans has suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079770/single-line-fromvalue-tovalue-not-a-class-not-a-dictionary-list-array-ho/8079961#8079961)?

Comment: @Jonas: I agree, it's a common problem, and a lot of implementations can be found online (e.g. a [DateRange class](http://huntjason.wordpress.com/2005/10/28/net-c-date-range-implementation-using-generics/)). Well, apparently it's not common enough to make it into the .NET Base Class Library...

Comment: @LukeH I agree. That's the point. Syntax does not fit in, where very high level of .NET code are used. Hans suggestion is fine except let such tiny task rely on a complete separate object.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a generic Range class:

```
public class MyRange<T> where T: IComparable
{
   public T From {get; private set;}
   public T Until {get; private set;}

   public MyRange(T from, T until)
   {
      From = from;
      Until = until;
   }

   public bool Contains(T value)
   {
      return value.CompareTo(From) >= 0 && value.CompareTo(Until) <= 0;
   }
}
```